# Django viewflow - create->pending->publish->edit->pending->publish

Tags: python, django, django-viewflow

I am using django viewflow to create a **publishing process**:

- user **creates** an object
- it goes into a **review** process and its status is **pending** (it is not visible to the public)
- when it is reviewed and approved it gets **published** and becomes publicly visible.
- if user **edits** this same entity it goes into the **review** process again, but the **old data is still visible to the public**

The part for creating and make it public is easy, but the part with editing not so much, if I want the old data to still be visible to the public. I was thinking to cancel saving the object on pre_save and save it just into the process model. But I did not manage to make it work. How can this be done with django viewflow? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Viewflow is the thin workflow layer that extracts flow logic out of views. The view logic that saves various data stays untouched.

To write a custom view you just need to add FlowMixin. It could be used as with generic.CreateView as with generic.UpdateView

Django CBV could look complicated, it that case you can use a simple functional based view, just mark it with `@flow_view` decorator. When task is finished, view should call `request.activation.done()`

Here is several custom views  sample, that you can check for the reference https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook/blob/master/custom_views/demo/bloodtest/views.py#L54